# Obtain suspended users in Craft3 Dev Preview

Tags: users, craft3

So I'm running into an issue where I'm given the users email. From there, I use the following code: `Craft::$app->getUsers()->getUserByEmail($email);`. This returns a null value, not because the user does not exists, but rather the status is set to suspended.

Is there a way to retrieve the `User` model from the email address, regardless of status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$user = User::find()
    ->email($email)
    ->status(null)
    ->one();
```